# Find out user rights on repositories in Sonatype Nexus

Tags: authorization, nexus, sonatype

I'm using Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.13.

I want to know on which repositories my user has which rights. Unfortunately I can't find such a view in the GUI.

Is there a way to find out which grants I have on which repository?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly hard to figure out, given the intersection of many different features such as Repo Routing, Repo Targets, etc...

I would suggest opening an issue over at our JIRA in regards: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS